# How properly set fields in anonymous class and use them in main class?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-volley, field, anonymous-class

I'm making app in Android Studio and I can't set value of fields in anonymous class.

I know that "receivedNumber" is always diffrent than '-1' and value "isExist" have to be 'true', but in log is 'false'. 
The same things happens with int field - always return '0'.
What should I do to set properly fields in anonymous class and use them in my main class.

```
private void isNumberExist()
{
        String URL = "some url...";
        final boolean[] isExist = new boolean[1];
        objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            int receivedNumber = response.getInt("id");
                            if (receivedNumber == -1) {                           
                                isExist[0] = false;                          
                            } else {     
                                isExist[0] = true;              
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       //error
                    }
                }
        );
        Log.e("isExist","value"+ isExist[0]);
        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
        requestQueue.cancelAll(this);
}
```

Comment: `Log.e("isExist","value"+ isExist[0]);` is probably being executed before `onResponse` is called.

Comment: @Justin I placed Log.e() on the end of method and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It will always be `false` because you are logging `isExist[0]` before the http(s) request is executed

Please try this

```java
private void isNumberExist()
{
    String URL = "some url...";
    final boolean[] isExist = new boolean[1];
    objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        int receivedNumber = response.getInt("id");
                        if (receivedNumber == -1) {                           
                            isExist[0] = false;                          
                        } else {     
                            isExist[0] = true;              
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // New log location
                    Log.e("isExist","value"+ isExist[0]);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //error
                }
            }
            );
    requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
    requestQueue.cancelAll(this);
}
```